# Sorting multi index data frame keeping index sorted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have a simple questions that I cannot figure out.

Basically I would like to filter a multi index by a column however keeping the index sorted.

original dataframe:

```
arrays = [['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
          ['Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('Animal', 'Type'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Max Speed': [100, 150, 360, 20]}, index=index)
```

[image]

desire output:

[image]

The standard sorting 'break' the first level of index which I would like to keep.

```
df.sort_values('Max Speed', ascending=False).sort_index(level=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Firstly reset your index by `reset_index()` method:

```
df=df.reset_index()
```

Finally use `sort_values()` method and chain `set_index()` method to it:

```
df=(df.sort_values(['Animal','Type','Max Speed'], ascending=[False,True,False])
 .set_index(['Animal','Type']))
```

Output of `df`:

```
                    Max Speed
Animal  Type    
Parrot  Captive     360
        Wild        20
Falcon  Captive     100
        Wild        150
```

Comment: could also use a chain of `stack` and `unstack` `df.unstack(0).stack(0).sort_values('Animal',ascending=False,axis=1).unstack(1).stack(0)` but I'm sure there is a better method, maybe with reindex.

Comment: @Umar.H Yup you was right There was a better method....Thanks **:)**

Comment: that is not correct, it's just sorting the index not the values change it to `True, True`

Comment: Since It is multiindex so values are also being sorted with indexes....idk it will work with real dataset or not but currently it is working for sample df provided by OP

Comment: If I change ascending to `True, True` then the 0th level will sort...i.e Falcon will come at top